# Neither min-width nor word-wrap help me to get content right shown if resolution is too small

Tags: html, word-wrap, css

I'm trying to develop a mobile site. Because the resolution could be low the design has to be flexible. Now I have four items (two rows with two cols):

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_ x ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

ccccccccccc / ddddddddddd                   | aaaaaaaaaa / bbbbbbbbbbb |

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_ x ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

zzzzzzzzzzzz                       | xxxxxxxxxx / yyyyyyyyyyyyyy |

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_ x ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

Now the text contains spaces and a slash, but at no time it makes a word break or something like that. I also tried to set a min-width, but except of FF every browser ignores this. Also I cannot set the min-width too high because of the low resolution of mobile devices.

zzzzzz / xxxxxxxx  and yyyyyyyyy are put in a new line if the window or resolution is too small. I want that the structure of two rows with two columns stays there. The text can wrap.

How can I reach this?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/85PZW/ Try to make the browser window smaller and see what happens. I want to keep the initial layout (if the windows is big enough).

**HTML**

```
<div class="SubpageMenu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="element first">
                    <a href="#">cccccccccc/ ddddddddddddddddddd</a>
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    <a href="#">aaaaaa / bbbbb</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="element first">
                    <a href="#">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</a>
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    <a href="#">xxxxxxxx / yyyyyyy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
 background-color:#000000;   
}

.SubpageMenu .row{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 43px;

}

.SubpageMenu .row .element{
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 43px;
    display: table;
}

.SubpageMenu .row  .element.first{
    border-right: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.SubpageMenu a{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I don't know why there is a word wrap at cccc / dddd, but in my real example there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... You might want to rethink your HTML markup first - are row 1 first and row 2 first related together?

When the resolution gets smaller does it really have to stay on 2 columns?

Automatic wordwrap only goes on spaces, on slashes not in IE, you can use the `&shy;` markup to make a break possible, but this is also not interpreted by every browser. More info on that [on selfhtml](http://de.selfhtml.org/html/text/zeilenumbruch.htm#erlauben) (German).

Another solution is to make the font smaller:

To be flexible it's better not to be fixed on this rows stuff:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element first">
    <a href="#">cccccccccc/ ddddddddddddddddddd</a>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <a href="#">aaaaaa / bbbbb</a>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <a href="#">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</a>
  </div>
  <div class="element last">
    <a href="#">xxxxxxxx / yyyyyyy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* the fontsize around the .container is 10px, 
the CSS would be as follows:*/

.container{
  width:16em;
  background:#000000;
}
.container .element{
  width:8em;
  float:left;
  height:3.6em;
  line-height:1.8em;
  padding:0.75em 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.element a{
  font-size:1.2em;
}
.element a:link,
.element a:visited{
  color:#FEFEFE;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.element a:hover,
.element a:focus{
  text-decoration:underline;
}


/* if you use a mobile js framework you surely have a 
<html> element class name with mobile detection */

.mobile .container{
  width: auto;
}

/* it's also possible to set a lower or higher font-size at a mobile device */

.mobile body{
  font-size:110%; /* just as example */
}
```

Comment: No the elements are not related. They don't have to stay two columns but now the font color is white on white background. If the layout is moved (through low screen resolution/small window size) than the user cannot read the text anymore. I have a background but this is not shown ...

Comment: How does the CSS look like if I put all elements in the container? The initial design should have two elements on a row.

Comment: /* the fontsize arround the .container is 10px, 
the CSS would be as follows:*/

    .container{
      width:16em;
    }
    .container .element{
      width:8em;
      float:left;
      height:3.6em;
      line-height:1.8em;
      padding:0.75em 0;
      text-align:center;
      }
      .element a{
        font-size:1.2em;
        }

/* if you use a mobile js framework you surely have a html class name with mobile detection */
      
      .mobile .container{
        width: auto;
        }

Comment: So you use em instead of px (thats better). I tried your design [here](http://jsfiddle.net/85PZW/12/) and the text from one element goes into the area of the other element. In addition, I'm afraid using line height. Especially if it is there a word wrap the alignment doesn't work anymore. This only works for one line elements I think.

Comment: yeah, maybe the line-height is to much here, but dont be afraid using it, just adapt it to fit -> do you have better examples of the text that will be used here? so if you have less space you should have short words. if the text comes from an title of somewhere else, think about having a shorttitle as an extra database field...